# How do I "install" a shared libray

Tags: software-installation, shared-library

I am developing a C++ application that uses external libraries, using gcc. For instance `libtiff` and `libpng`. I obtained these by `apt-get` and everything is working fine.

But then I added another third party library delivered as a stand-alone pair of `.a` and `.so` `lib` files. I detected that the other `.so` are stored in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, and I copied the new `.so` there. I successfully linked my application but execution fails with the message "`error while loading shared libraries: libThirdParty.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`"

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways for a application for find its libraries:

- The environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Set it to the paths with your libs, colon-separated. Check whether it is not empty first (`echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) and in that case expand it, for example `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/foo/lib:/home/myself/lib`. This is fine for testing or if you are neither `root` no a sudoer, you can add it to your shell initialization (like `.zshrc`) if you want it permanently. But of course it's slower to parse a variable and search for files, that's why you usually prefer the second approach:
- After copying the libs, call `ldconfig` as root or with `sudo`. This scans standard library paths (`/lib` and `/usr/lib` or `/lib64` and `/usr/lib64`) and paths from config file `/etc/ld.so.conf` and paths given as arguments to `ldconfig` for libraries and updates the `ld.so` library cache for the whole system.

Comment: My `LD_CONFIG_PATH` is empty, but the other libraries are found anyway in the same path.

Comment: Yes, because they have been cached by calling `ldconfig`. `apt` did do that for you after installation. In my comment I suggested to go that way, too. Now I added the other possibility to make a complete answer out of it.

Comment: As mentioned in my comments, I cannot confirm if the problem was due to ldconfig not performed or just inappropriate file access protection.

Comment: As a third option, you could set the ELF's `RUNPATH` during linking with `-Wl,-rpath=`.  This works well if you plan to re-distribute the third party library in your re-locatable package, but I do prefer the `ldconfig` solution as long as you don't expect your users to manually do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

First, your external libraries should be installed, rather then copied to library location. Install script would put them in `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib`*.
That would make things easier.

And when it comes to the location of your library then I would suggest `/usr/local/lib`*.

Now, it (`/usr/local/lib`) may need to be put in `/etc/ld.so.conf` if you haven't done it yet and, if so, you need to run `/sbin/ldconfig`. It's not necessary if it's done already.

Eventually, you can check whether your library i found with:
`ldconfig -p | grep your_library.so`.

* or `/usr/lib64` or `/usr/local/lib64` for x86_64

Comment: You have a good sense of humor. The case is already solved and you suggest a more complex solution (not counting that the problem was elsewhere). Why making it simple when you can bang your head against the wall ;-)

Comment: Maye it was more general but [you had said yourself](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/702860/how-do-i-install-a-shared-libray/702898?noredirect=1#comment1329152_702860), running `ldconfig` hadn't worked, so I elaborated on the topic bit more. Don't like it, thumb it down.

Comment: Why would I change the location of the libraries "to make things easier" (especially if 
 a `.conf` file needs to be updated) ??

Comment: Because you want to install external libraries. First so they are accessible, and so they can be uninstalled, reinstalled, upgraded. When you put them in place only known to you, only you can access, ur/re/install/upgrade them and other programs that use them may not be able to use them.

Comment: In my context, there is no need for that, thanks.